# Subsetting two factors -- ‘&’ not meaningful for factors

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to filter two variables in my `data.frame` by specified conditions.

I want to subset two variable factors: a) Ratings b) Location

I filtered the ratings variable in order to select those ratings which are relevant to me, ie, ratings == 0.

Now, I would now like select the 'Location' variable that only have a Ratings == 0, but am unable to do so. I know it is subsetting but cant get code right....But not filtering the ''location'' variable my location variable will number more than my Rating variable.

I tried the below code but I am getting an error:

```
Unrated_MraLevel1 <- xyz[(MRA == "0" & xyzLocation)]
```

> error msg : In Ops.factor(MRA== "0", xyz$Location) :
>     ‘&’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: Convert it to character and it should work i.e. `xyz[(as.character(MRA) == "0" & xyzLocation)]`  It is better to provide a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: What is `xyzLocation`? You are not comparing it to anything. What you are doing could be easily reproduced, for instance `2 & factor(2)`. I think you are trying to do `xyz[xyz$MRA == 0, "Location"]`

Comment: `& xyzLocation` would only make sense if `xyzLocation` was a boolean variable.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, xyz is the Dataframe, and Location is one of the varaibles in my DF. Basically given that I filtered/subset  the ratings varaible to == 0, now I want to filter the  Locations varaible  where ratings == 0.  so that I can eventually plot the two varaibles. i.e - I only want locations where their ratings ==0

Comment: I've provided the code for that in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description this is what you want.

Example data:

```
dd <- data.frame(location=rep(letters[1:3],each=3),
                 MRA=c(rep(0,3),1:3,c(2,0,0)))
```

Aggregate data to find levels where all `location` values are equal to zero:

```
a <- aggregate(MRA~location,dd,FUN=function(x) all(x==0))
```

Extract the levels to keep:

```
keep.levels <- a$location[a$MRA]
```

Subset the data set:

```
dd[dd$location %in% keep.levels,]
```